# swapping lower letters and upper letters

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
   char letter,letter1;
   cin>>letter;
   char change_to_lower(letter);
   char change_to_upper(letter);
   char  swap(letter);
   return 0;
}

char change_to_lower(char a){
    if(a=='a'&& a<='z'){
        char b= toupper(a);
        return b;
    }
}

char change_to_upper(char a){
    if(a=='A'&& a<='Z'){
        char b = tolower(a);
        return b;
    }
}

char  swap(char a){
    char letter1,letter2;
    a=change_to_lower(letter1);
    char b=change_to_upper(letter1);
    char temp = a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
    cout<< a<<" "<< b<<endl;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: am new to functions and strings and i was wondering  if anyone can help me out.

Comment: i wanna swap the small letter to capital letters and vice versa . plz lemme know where am wrong

Comment: you should add your question to the question, not post in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to convert all uppercase characters to lowercase characters and lowercase letters to uppercase letters, in a string?

```
void swapuplo(char *s)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
        if (isupper(s[i]))
            s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        else if (islower(s[i]))
            s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
}
```

This is the calling routine

```
int main()
{
    char buf[] = "HeLLo WORLD";
    swapuplo(buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hEllO world
```

Be sure to include `<ctype.h>`, which contains the declarations for the character testing functions.

Comment: thanks for your help. am trying to change char to lower or capital letter. forexample if the input is a, the output should  be A and vice versa

Comment: if i may ask, why do u use pointers? does  it make it much easier? is there any other way it can be done without pointers?

Comment: I pass the address of the first character of the string to `swapuplow`, because **when passed to functions** arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: thanks alot. i need to learn more about pointers:) it was helpfull